# spring RESTful service work fine, but throws an exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring RESTful service, and it is working. My client send an object into a put request and my service receive this object perfectly, but after this, my client receive this exception: "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found"

This is my client code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    Greeting greeting = new Greeting(21l, FileUtils.toByteArray("src/main/resources/test.png"));         
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/DolphinRestServer/bulletin/put";

    restTemplate.put(url,greeting);
```

And this is my server code:

```
@Service
@RequestMapping("/bulletin")
public class BulletinService {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/put")
    public void put(@RequestBody Greeting greeting){
        System.out.println("it's work fine and my greeting is here --------->"+greeting);
    }
}
```

When tested, i get those messages:

**-server side:**
[image]

**-Client side:**

[image: Client side image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `put` method has a `void` return type.  Additionally, it does not take the `HttpServletResponse` as a parameter.  According to the [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types), when such a situation arises, Spring MVC uses the URL as the view name and attempts to render it.  In your case, Spring MVC is attempting to find and load a view called `/bulletin/put`, which it can't find and hence the 404 message.

Comment: Was exactly what was happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see it is making another request at 20:40:34:085 DolphinRestServer/bulletin/bulletin/put in the server side giving an error page not found.

And it is because you are calling BulletinService twice.

You defined as a bean and it has an annotation. Make sure you are only loading/scanning this package once..

**Remove @service annotation on BulletinService**

Comment: removing **@Service** or **@RequestMapping** i get the same exception and my request doesn't work anymore  :/